# Select statements inside a WHERE IN() clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Given these tables:

```
Product(maker, model)
Desktop(model)
Laptop(model)
```

I want to know the makers that make both a laptop and a desktop.

If I wanted to know if a maker makes two specific models  I would do it like this:

```
SELECT p.maker FROM Product p
WHERE p.model IN ('model1', 'model2')
GROUP BY p.maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.model) = 2;
```

In this case I don't need the specific models but I  need to know that one model must be a laptop and the other one a desktop.

Should I do it using select statements inside the IN clause like this?

```
SELECT p.maker FROM Product p
WHERE p.model IN ((SELECT d.model FROM Desktop d WHERE d.model=p.model),
                  (SELECT l.model FROM Laptop d WHERE l.model=p.model))
GROUP BY p.maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.model) = 2;
```

Or is there another better way to do it?

Edit: as suggested by HoneyBadger using EXISTS is a better way to do it:

```
SELECT p.maker FROM Product p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT d.model FROM Desktop d WHERE d.model=p.model)
AND EXISTS(SELECT l.model FROM Laptop d WHERE l.model=p.model)
GROUP BY p.maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.model)>1;
```

Comment: I think two `EXISTS` would read a lot simpler, and perhaps perform better too

Comment: *"Can I do it using select statements inside the IN clause like this?"* try it and tell us

Comment: You can try UNION in you IN statement instead of comma separated sub selects

Comment: I'd consider having one computers table, instead of one for laptops and one for desktops.

Comment: @HoneyBadger You are right, in this specific case two EXISTS clause linked by an AND would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.maker FROM Product p
WHERE p.model IN (
      (SELECT d.model FROM Desktop d WHERE d.model=p.model 
       UNION
       SELECT l.model FROM Laptop d WHERE l.model=p.model
      )
    )
GROUP BY p.maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.model) = 2;
```

I'd also look to refactor these into the same table, with a type field that can specify desktop vs laptop. I understand a laptop may have some different attributes (screen, camera/mic, bluetooth, etc)

Comment: Use UNION ALL instead of UNION for avoiding extra order inside engine. That makes slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

Exists is a method of getting the required information. The marked as answer reply is not the correct answer considering one maker could be making more than one desktop and more than one laptop too. It doesn't make it mandatory to have models from  both desktop and laptop.

Here is one more way of getting that information. Try to check this also.

```
select maker, COUNT(DISTINCT(modeltype)) As ModelTypes FROM
(
select p.*, 'Desktop' As "ModelType" from Product p 
    inner join Desktop d on p.model = d.model
Union ALL
select p.*, 'Laptop' As "ModelType" from Product p 
    inner join Laptop l on p.model = l.model
) A
group by maker
having count(DISTINCT(modeltype)) = 2
```